# Interfaces with respect to the term API

Tags: java, terminology

I am trying to get a handle on the above. I understand that an interface contains method signatures with no implementation. That task is left up to the classes that implement the interface. I am struggling to understand though how interfaces relate to API. We import packages into our classes when we want to use arraylists or fonts right? But what interface are we implementing? Any help would be appreciated...thanks

java.awt.font==>Provides classes and interface relating to fonts.

Comment: The question as it stands doesn't make a lot of sense. Can you clarify what it is you're unsure of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not implementing *any* interface by `import`ing a package--you're just providing some syntactic sugar to make writing Java code marginally less painful than it would be otherwise. In the bytecode, everything is always fully-qualified.

An interface may *define* an API, or it may be *part* of an API.

A package may *contain* an API, or be *part* of an API, or just random stuff.

You're only implementing an interface if you actually *implement* an interface--otherwise you're just *using* an interface, or *referencing* an interface. This *requires* that a package/class/interface be imported, but simply importing the same is not sufficient.

Comment: Well said. I especially like the emphasis added to the words implement, using, and referencing. It helps clarify the difference.